# Call to Action - how can I make the call to action element to be full screen on elementor please?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I created a Call to Action on the homepage and want to make it full screen - how can I do that please?

resolution to know how to do it?
Also there are some wording in the description next to the photo in the Call to action, how can I add space between each line (not the header - I only need to add space between each line of the decription below the header) ?